# C# Yahoo Weather, get all attributes from yweather:condition

Tags: c#, xml, rss, yahoo-weather-api

What I would like to do is access the yahoo weather xml from the rss, and get the data specifically from the yweather:condition tag. I tried with

```
xdoc.Load("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=MKXX0001&u=c");
XmlNode xNode = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition");
```

But with no success. How can I access the xml from yahoo weather and get all the attributes there? Also, how can I save all the attributes to my local xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is wrong

Expected XPath should be

```
/rss/channel/item/yweather:condition
```

Other things are, XPath contains prefix so you need to specify namespacemanager.

Your Code should be

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=MKXX0001&u=c");
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");
XmlNode xNode = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/item/yweather:condition", nsmgr);
```

Comment: then how can i save the data to my local document  xdoc2.Load("data.xml")?

Comment: @user2962759: You can save the xml from xdoc using OuterXml property that is `xdoc.OuterXml`. To read all the attributes, you need to iterate through `xNode.Attributes`

Answer (score 0):

Learn XPath to know how to select every particular element of the xml. Yahoo weather xml has namespaces, so you'll need `XmlNamespaceManager` as second argument for `SelectSingleNode` method. This example demonstrate how to get all attributes from `<yweather:condition>` element :

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=MKXX0001&u=c");
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");
var _attributes = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel/item/yweather:condition", nsmgr).Attributes;
foreach (XmlAttribute attr in _attributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attribute: {0}, Value: {1}", attr.Name, attr.Value);
}
```